# Need to understand this If statement

Tags: c

I need to understand more about this if condition the two sides of comparison and how it is compared:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned short i;
    if (i == '9' * 256 + '5')
    {
        /* Do stuff */
    }
}
```

How are these compared?

Comment: Why do you need that? That looks like code you would get fired for writing. :)

Comment: Unfortunately your question is unclear: What do you not understand?

Comment: Lookup ASCII value of `'9'`, same for `'5'`; plug them in.

Comment: Re-format your question after reading this  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you leave something out of your post?  What value do you expect `i` to have?

Answer (score 1):

Formally the behaviour of your code is *undefined* as you are reading the uninitialised variable `i`.

`'9'`, 256, and `'5'` are *all* `int` types in C. So the right hand side is evaluated in `int` arithmetic, with the potential for overflow (it will not overflow with ASCII encoding).

`i` will be converted to an `int` type prior to the comparison.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Yeah that added confusion and there's no need to go into all the exceptions; I've trimmed the text.